# Using func.max and func.count in one query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
class Shops(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    order = db.relationship('Order', backref = 'purchased', lazy = 'dynamic')

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    shop = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('shop.id'))
```

I want to get the highest selling shop based on order, like so:

```
query = db.session.query(Shops.name.label('TopShop'),Order,func.max(func.count(Order.shop)))
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1111, u'Invalid use of group function')
```

Any pointers in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top shop(s) by *number of orders*:

```
subq = (session.query(Order.shop, func.count(Order.id).label("num_orders")).
        group_by(Order.shop)).subquery()
q = session.query(Shops).join(subq, Shops.id == subq.c.shop).order_by(subq.c.num_orders.desc())

# top 1
print q.first()
# top 5
print q[:5]
```